# A positive real number $x$ with the property $x^3=3$ is irrational.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-writing, real-numbers

I have the following problems:

1) There exists a positive real number $x$ such that $x^3=3$.

2) A positive real number $x$ with the property $x^3=3$ is irrational.

My Idea for 1) would be (there might be a few mistakes here):

Let $S = \{ x  \geq  0 |  x^3 \leq  3\}$, with $1\ge0$ and $1^3=1$ we have $1 \in S$, so $S \neq \emptyset$. With that we have $\forall x \in S, x < 3$, so S is bounded above. With the upper bound property of real numbers, $S$ has a least upper bound $s$: 
$s=sup(S)$.

Since $1$ is in $S $, we know that $s>1$. 
Now $s$ either is the solution, or one of the follwing two cases are true:

I) $s^3<3$

Let: $\varepsilon = \frac{3-s^3}{3s+1}$. By assumption $0<\varepsilon<1$, so that:

$(s+\varepsilon)^3=s^3+3s^2\varepsilon+3s\varepsilon^2+\varepsilon^3 \le s^3+3s^2\varepsilon+3s\varepsilon^2+\varepsilon^2=s^3+\frac{3-s^3}{3s+1}(3s+1)=3$.

Hence, $s + \varepsilon$  is also in $S$, in which case $s$ can not be an upper bound for $S$. This is a contradiction, so this case is not possible.

II) $s^3>3$

Let: $\varepsilon = \frac{s^3-3}{3s}$. Again $\varepsilon>0$, so that:

$(s-\varepsilon)^3=s^3-3s^2\varepsilon+3s\varepsilon^2-\varepsilon^3\ge s^3-3s^2\varepsilon+3s\varepsilon^2=s^3-3s\frac{s^3-3}{3s}=3.$

Hence, $s -\varepsilon$  is another upper bound for $S$, so that $s$ is not the least upper bound for $S$. This is a contradiction, so that this case is not possible.

Having eliminated these two cases, we are left with $s^3 = 3$, which is what we wanted to prove.

2) However I don't know how to proof that a positive real number with the property $x^3=3$ is irrational. It would be really nice if someone could help!

Edit: Made a correction regarding $(s+\varepsilon)^3$ and $(s-\varepsilon)^3$ (Hope this is correct)

Comment: For the first, do you not yet have access to the intermediate value theorem?  For the second, do you know how to show that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational (this is often one of the first proofs that students are taught in upper division classes)?  The proof that $\sqrt[3]{3}$ is irrational is similar.

Comment: Try it by contradiction. Suppose there exists a rational and try to show that it cant happen.

Comment: Let $\frac ab$ be such that $a,b$ are integers and $(\frac ab)^3=3$ so $3b^3 = a^3$ so $3|a^3$.... is this looking familiar to you?

Comment: Fun fact: If you had a value $\sqrt [n] {n}$ then the largest value of this form is obtained if you let $n = 3$

Comment: The very first time we prove the that $\sqrt 2$ is irrational we don't use the unique prime factorization as, in spirit, we are *introducing* the concept of the l.u.b. principal and *the need* for it. and the UPF undermines that in using the well-ordering principal.  But can you use it now.  If $3b^3 = a^3$ then the LHS is divisible by some power $3k+1$ of $3$ whereas the RHS is divisble by some power $3m$.  $3m = 3k+1$ is not compatible.  ... At any rate, proving irrational should not be the difficult part.

Comment: Here is another set of examples as a source of inspiration https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2482457/there-is-no-rational-number-r-with-the-property-r2-3/ or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2511028/show-that-there-are-no-rationals-r-such-that-r3-6/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prove it's irrational, proceed just like in the proof that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational. Assume there are integers, in lowest terms, such that $\frac{a^3}{b^3} = 3$. So, $a^3 = 3b^3$. Show that $3$ must divide both $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Ok: if $\frac ab$ is rational, we have $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $b \in \mathbb{N}$. With the definition of divisibility we have $a^3=3b^3 $and with that: $3|a^3$ and $3|a$. Since $a^3$ and $a$ are both divisible by 3, we can say that $a=3r$, so we have: $(3r)^3=3b^3 \to 27r^3=3b^3 \to 9r^3=b^3$. With that we see that b is also divisible by $3$, which is a contraidction. With that $x^3=3$ is irrational.

Comment: @MatheSt Perfect.

Answer (score 2):

You don't justify with if $x^3<3$ then $x<3$; it is in fact very easy to check that if $x^3<3$, then $x<2$.

In case I, you want to deal with $s+\epsilon$, and not with $s-\epsilon$; otherwise, there is no contradiction.

I didn't check your inequalities carefully, but it should be something like that.

Regarding irrationality, you assume that $x$ is rational, write the equation, and you get a contradiction by looking at the prime decompositions.

Comment: Yeah, I made a mistake there. Hope this is correct now.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative proof: assuming that the positive solution of $x^3=3$ is a rational number, we have that $x^3-3$ factors over $\mathbb{Q}$, hence it factors over any finite field $\mathbb{F}_p$. Let us consider $p=19$. The cubic residues $\!\!\pmod{19}$ are $0,\pm 1,\pm 7,\pm 8$. $3$ is not one of them, hence $x^3-3$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_{19}$ and it is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$, too. It follows that $\sqrt[3]{3}\not\in\mathbb{Q}$.

---

The same approach for proving the irrationality of $\sqrt{2}$: $x^2-2$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_7$, hence it is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$, too.